# Unable to coerce during `DerivingVia` when using optics types like `Prism'`

Tags: haskell, coercion, derivingvia, haskell-optics

I'm unable to automatically derive instances using `DerivingVia` on any type that uses types from [`optics-core`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics-0.4/docs/Optics.html) like `Prism'`; the error I get from compiler is:

```
src/Main.hs:24:13-19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Foo’ with ‘Stringable Foo’
        arising from the coercion of the method ‘mkPrism’
          from type ‘MyPrism (Stringable Foo)’ to type ‘MyPrism Foo’
    • When deriving the instance for (MkPrism Foo)
   |
24 |   deriving (MkPrism) via (Stringable Foo)
   |             ^^^^^^^
```

The type in question is:

```hs
newtype MyPrism a
  = MyPrism (Prism' String a)
```

The compilation succeeds if I replace the `Prism'` type with its underlying representation, viz.:

```hs
newtype MyPrism a
  = MyPrism (a -> String, String -> Maybe a)
```

- Why do I see coercion issues when using `Prism'`? Is it because [the `Optic` constructor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics-core-0.4/docs/src/Optics.Internal.Optic.html#Optic) is not exported by the package?
- What is the usual way to solve this?

You can see the full program to reproduce this here: https://github.com/srid/q-optics-coercion/blob/f1e3df5e1c5c0e4a51eacb6439fb8c627e4c7bd5/src/Main.hs ... if you have Nix installed, you can run `bin/run` in this repo.

---

**EDIT**: Once I `import Optics.Internal.Optic`, the error message becomes:

```
src/Main.hs:25:13-19: error:
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘p i Foo Foo’
                               with that of ‘p i (Stringable Foo) (Stringable Foo)’
        arising from the coercion of the method ‘mkPrism’
          from type ‘MyPrism (Stringable Foo)’ to type ‘MyPrism Foo’
    • When deriving the instance for (MkPrism Foo)
   |
25 |   deriving (MkPrism) via (Stringable Foo)
   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, profunctor optics (such as those used in the `lens` and `optics` packages) aren't directly coercible.  Roughly speaking, the internal representation of a prism is something like:

```
newtype Prism' s a 
  = Prism' (forall p f. (Choice p, Applicative f) => p a (f a) -> p s (f s))
```

(Well, at least that's what it is for `Control.Lens`.  For `Optics.Core`, it might be a little more complicated.)

The problem here is that `a` and `s` appear as parameters to higher-kinded type variables (`f` and `p`) in this type.  As a result, their "roles" are nominal (see the [Role Inference](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/roles.html#role-inference) section in the GHC manual for an explanation why), and these nominal roles prevent direct coercion.

Fortunately, there are some functions in `Optics.Coerce` that are designed to deal with this.  You won't be able to derive a `MyPrism` type directly via the newtype, but you should be able to write:

```
instance MkPrism Foo where
  mkPrism = MyPrism . coerceA . coerceB $ p
    where MyPrism p = mkPrism :: MyPrism (Stringable Text)
```